# If an old question wasn't answered, is there a good way to bump it?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have the same question previously asked as ["Stop iTunes from automatically stopping podcast downloads"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11012/stop-itunes-from-automatically-stopping-podcast-downloads). I don't think there was a satisfactory answer 3.5 years ago, and now one of the top answers even includes a broken link. Perhaps things have changed since then?

Is there an accepted way to bump this question? I could edit it, add a bounty, or ask a similar question again either here or on Superuser.

Answer (score 3):

Editing for the sake of bumping is discouraged, as is posting duplicate questions. Bounties are appropriate, but you only have 121 reputation.

It would be reasonable, though, to ask a new question and specify that your new question is asking specifically about what is available in 2014 using iTunes version (whatever) running on operating system version whatever. Even link to the old question to let people know you know about it but are looking for something more current.

Comment: Thanks. I have asked a specific question following your suggestion, ["Prevent iTunes 12 for Windows from stopping podcast update"](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164365/prevent-itunes-12-for-windows-from-stopping-podcast-update).