# What to do if your question is already old and ignored, but still unanswered?

Tags: discussion

I still need to find a solution to my problem.

Can I repost the same question?

Can I "bump" the old question?

Do I just have to give up on this site (for this question) and look for help at another site?

[This meta question](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/if-an-old-question-wasnt-answered-is-there-a-good-way-to-bump-it) is kind of the same as my question.

Is a bounty the only acceptable way to "bump" a question?

Comment: Which old question would you like to „reactivate“?

Comment: @nohillside Well, it's irrelevant now as I managed to find the solution myself (and I updated the relevant question with an answer).  However, the answer below will be useful if I ever have an unanswered question again, or if anyone else does for that matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/295232); Ask Different generally follows the guidelines set there:

> 1. You can "bump" your question by editing it to **provide status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the question yourself**, or to explain why the existing answers didn't work. I usually do that unless I really hit a dead end with no further clues to follow. Sometimes I eventually bring about enough understanding to realize the answer, and then post a self-answer to my question.
> 2. If you have at least **75** reputation, you can [offer a **bounty**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties), promising to give some of your reputation to a user who answers your question. This causes your question to receive additional attention, as it will be added to a special list and be promoted more than normal questions.
> 3. If there is an unsatisfactory answer, you could leave a specific comment on that answer to ask for clarification or suggest an improvement to clear up anything you don't understand.
> 4. Post a link to the question on the site's chat. Usually active users of the site will hang out there, and they can offer further help.
> 5. Use the **share** button beneath your question to advertise it to your networks. Then, if you find the answer, you can post a self-answer to help others who come across the same question.
>
> **Do not post your question a second time,** as it will be closed as a duplicate of your first question, and may attract downvotes. Also, **do not delete your question and re-ask it,** as your previous question will be undeleted and your new one closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a perfect answer, and it's in TFM.  Doh.  Anyway, I was editing my original comment as I worked on the problem so it turns out I was already following these guidelines unintentionally.